# Game with a 0-1 matrix, where Alice tries to make a large row sum and Bob tries to make a large column sum.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, game-theory

Two players, Alice and Bob take turns in filling in the cells of a $19 \times 19$ grid (which is initially empty). Alice writes a $1$ in her chosen cell, and Bob writes a $0$ in his chosen cell. When all cells are filled in, they calculate the sum of each row, and the sum of each column. Let the largest row sum be $A$, and let the largest column sum be $B$. If $A > B$ then Alice wins the game. Bob wins if $B > A$, and it is a draw if $A = B$. Does either player have a winning strategy?

Points I have gotten:

- Alice can force a draw as the diagonal has an odd number of cells, so it's Alice who can avoid ever making an off-diagonal move what's not a response to the opponent.
- Alice can simply copy cat off Bobs move, mirroring his moves along a diagonal, and choosing a random choice in the diagonal when he chooses a square on the diagonal.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the game, but it looks as if the sum over the square will be $\lfloor 19^2/2 \rfloor = 180$ and so the maximum row and column must be at least $\lceil 180/19\rceil =10$.  Alice can avoid losing if she prevents any column being $11$ or more and  Bob can avoid losing if he prevents any row being $11$ or more, and that looks easy, just by Alice following any of Bob's moves in the same column and Bob following any of Alice's moves in the same row (if a row or column is full, or Alice's first move, then they get a free move elsewhere)

Comment: @Henry They don't have to alternatively write 0 then 1. They get to choose whether they want to use 0 or 1. EG They could end up with a all 0's table.

Comment: @CalvinLin You may be correct, but I see the word *respectively* which I read as Alice writing $0$ and Bob $1$

Comment: @Henry Ah true. OP will have to clarify what they mean then (since the respectively would contradict their points) $\quad$ With your interpretation, I agree with your comment.

Comment: @Henry Alice writes 1's and Bob writes 0's

Comment: OK so same comment as originally but  sum over the square will be $\lceil19^2/2\rceil=181$ so the maximum row and column must be at least $\lceil181/19\rceil=10$

Comment: @Henry Have you taken into consideration my previous comment? I was wrong to say that Alice and Bob have free will. They do not, Alice can only write 1 and bob 0.

Comment: @LudonMahraj my original comment had Alice writing $0$ and Bob $1$, so your change makes little or no practical difference